# Accessing Data in an R workspace

Tags: r

I am self taught with R. There may be very basic things I may not be familiar with. If so I apologize.

I am trying to access data provided to me by an outside source. It comes as a workspace. My process is as follows:

```
>ls()
[1] "2003OHT-HR"
> attach(2003OHT-HR)
Error: unexpected symbol in "attach(2003OHT"
```

I assume "-" is an illegal character or something but I don't know what to do about it. I've looked around and tried a couple other things but I can't seem to access it. Anything I could do to access the data would be great, even exporting it to a different format or something. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get around it by enclosing the data-frame in backticks, like so:

```
> `2003OHT-HR` <- data.frame(Normal=rnorm(100))
> head(`2003OHT-HR`)
             Normal
1 -1.28498109551429
2 -0.71140764617235
3 -0.21274972139595
4  1.36845373456725
5  0.05221904829256
6 -1.64995142910773
>
```